# Optimize Plotly Parallel plot

Tags: r, plot, graph, graphics, plotly

I am doing a parallel plot with plotly. It works, but get very time consuming when I apply it to huge data, because I am doing as many "trace" as markers.

How can I do it faster?

There is a reproducible example showing how I do it yet :

```
#Create data
markers=paste("markers",letters,sep="_")
data=data.frame(
    mark=rep(markers,3),
    map=c(rep(1,26) , rep(2,26) , rep(3,26)),
    pos=sample(seq(1:100) , 26*3)
    )

# Make the plot with Plotly
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data , x=map , y=pos, mode="markers+lines"  , group=mark)
```

And that is the result

[My current plotly parallel plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViiEe.png)

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

For each trace, plotly.js must calculate default plot and layout data, so the initial plot will not be very fast. For large data sets, you should use the `scattergl` plot type instead of `scatter`, but ideally, you should re-arrange your data so that you don't need to plot as many traces (if this is possible).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Miklos! I don't mind rearranging my dataset in whatever format! I just have no idea what format would be the most appropriate.. Concerning the scattergl plot type, how can I call it with plotly ? Thanks again

Comment: To create a scattergl plot, you can just add `type='scattergl'` to your call to `plot_ly`. This alone should speedup the plot, but beyond that, you would be best to consolidate the data points to a single trace - that is, only have a single x list and y list that you are plotting.

Full disclosure - I don't know a ton of R, but I work on plotly.js!

Answer (score 1):

Now there's a native parallel coordinates trace `parcoords` in `plotly.js` which was built for scalable operations, e.g. uses the GPU for crossfiltering and rendering. Some of the styling is therefore more constrained than with regular `lines`. Besides the brush filtering, it also has axis drag and drop by grabbing the axis title.

Doc: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#parcoords

Examples:

- https://plot.ly/javascript/parallel-coordinates-plot/
- https://codepen.io/monfera/pen/dNBwOv

As usual, the functionality is accessible via the Python, R etc. API bindings too, e.g. https://plot.ly/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/

It's an older question, just adding this answer for future search hits on this page.